# Is it possible in JavaScript to create a div, put a \u#### character in that div, then copy to canvas as a putImage?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working with fTelnet.js - I have gotten down to the this_Font.GetChar() code and have found all characters are from a Font Sprite, it getItemData(....) changes the color where The pixel is 0x80 and colors it foreground [r][g][b][alpha], or colors it background [r][g][b][alpha].

Since Unicode goes outside what is in its 40+ fonts - I need to cheat and .createElement("div"), .innerHTML = "\u#####"; then somehow take that as ImageData so I can patch the above logic and introduce unicode support to fTelnet's canvas routine.

Does anyone know what command(s) I am needed to do this? e.g. I have spent hours trying to resolve this via Google, HTML5 Context docs, without success... mainly not knowing what I am searching for ;-)

or as I re-read this... maybe a hidden canvas, do the ctx.strokeText("\u#####", 25, 50); and then copy from that CTX as a IMAGEDATA to the displayed? (what command would I look up then?)... I normally do not dabble in 2D/3D graphics world (obviously)...

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, rendering HTML to canvas is not possible - and that seems to be by design (it would make issues like tainting much harder to navigate).

But stamping one canvas on top of another is simple - you can just use the standard `#drawImage` call, same as with any other image you would draw on canvas.

Actually, if you [look at the API documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#2dcontext) and click through the definitions you will see that you can use drawImage to "stamp" any instance of svg or html image, a bitmap, offscreen canvas, video or audio tags.